# How to hide svg from the page?

Tags: html, svg

I have 4 elements on the page which use the same svg gradient

`<svg>
    <defs>
         <linearGradient id="gradient">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: deepPink"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #009966"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>`

And I just want to define it once on the page and it isn't supposed to be visible. But this svg block move other blocks on the page and has dimensions 150x300

These svg blocks are supposed to be visible on the page and use the above svg gradient.

`<svg>
    <rect width="100" height="100" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="5" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
<svg>
    <rect width="100" height="100" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="5" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for the width and height attributes on the `svg` element is 100%, which means the SVG viewport depends on the parent container it's in.

From the [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html):

> The SVG user agent negotiates with its parent user agent to determine the viewport into which the SVG user agent can render the document.

To solve your issue you can set the width and height attributes to `0` directly on the `svg` tag, but it's also possible to use CSS.

To prevent `svg` elements to take up space on the page use `display: none`.  I'm not sure about browser support of gradients in this case, but there are work arounds. Check [this Bugzilla post](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=376027).

Comment: Yeah, I tried. But the svg block take up space anyway.

Comment: If you use display:none the gradient won't work in Firefox at least.

Comment: display: none; is good. But I also needed to add position: absolute

Comment: <svg width="0" height="0"> is the only solution without any issue

Answer (score 6):

The following CSS worked for me to hide the block.

```
svg defs {
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}
```

As stated in other answers, `display:none` will break the def and `visibility:hidden` still takes space on the page.

Comment: visibility:hidden also makes any mask elements in the def unusable

Comment: I've made myself a helper class `.is-off-screen` with these styles and `left: -9999em;` that I'm using to hide my SVG symbols as I saw issues with SVGs using 'map' when using `visibility: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the definition SVG give it width and height attributes of 0

Comment: `Visibility: hidden` will still take up space on the page. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way that works for me. I set width and height attribute to 0 and also set the display attribute to none like this.

```
<svg width="0" height="0" display="none">
  <defs>
    <g id="my-object">...</g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: display="none" looks useless, setting width and height to 0 is enough.